# Turning off screen power when the screen saver kicks in

Tags: power-management, screensaver

One of my laptops (a HP one) is rarely in active use but is always on, basically used remotely and for backup purposes. However, the screen is always powered on, even when the screen saver (black screen) kicks in. A dim light emanates from the screen all the time, which is unwanted.

Is it possible to turn the screen power OFF when the screensaver is active?

Details from settings/about:

Hardware Model: HP Laptop 15s-eq1xxx
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 4500u with radeon graphics
Graphics: AMD Renoir
OS: Ubuntu 21.10, 64-bit

Comment: @user68186 The laptop in question has some issues with hibernating when the lid is closed. I now did a complete restart, which helped the situation a lot. At the moment the screen goes black when the screen saver activates, as it should. Guess I'll just have to turn it off properly before I take it outside on the balcony next time. Case closed AFAIK, but I'll edit the question a bit tomorrow. Good night :)

Comment: I am glad you found a partial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is found. This laptop has problems with hibernation when the lid is closed. A complete restart fixed the stray light from the screen, and a working solution is to always power off before closing the lid – I can live with that.